# Liferay custom sql query with date

Tags: sql, liferay

I am trying to write a custom sql query in liferay portal. The following is the query.

```sql
SELECT sum(score) as total FROM ratingsentry r  WHERE r.modifiedDate>?;
```

The util function is as following.

```java
String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get("GET_TODAY_COUNT");              
SQLQuery q = dbSession.createSQLQuery(sql);
QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(q);        

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);               
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = CalendarUtil.getTimestamp(cal.getTime());      
qPos.add(timestamp);

q.addScalar("total", Type.LONG );                                   
Object count=q.uniqueResult();
```

From the above util method, te count is always returned as 0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of timestamp?

Comment: My understanding is that Liferay uses MySQL. what happens when you use something like MySQL workbench to execute `SELECT sum(score) as total FROM ratingsentry r WHERE r.modifiedDate > '1/1/2010'`

Comment: No, Liferay is essentially database agnostic and uses Hibernate under the covers, but it does have some custom code for several databases (eg DB2 and Oracle) to enforce consistent behaviour. It uses HSQL out of the box but warns you not to use that in production.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```java
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

I pass on the query within a service builder in case it can help you:

```
String myParameter = "?";

DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = dynamicQuery();
        
ProjectionList projectionList = ProjectionFactoryUtil.projectionList();
projectionList.add(ProjectionFactoryUtil.sum("score"));

dynamicQuery.setProjection(projectionList);
dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.gt("modifiedDate", myParameter));
List<Object[]> results = logCalendarioPersistence.findWithDynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
```

As a general rule (I don't know if this will be your case) aggregation functions need a "group by", which in this case would be grouped by the value in question of your table, for this, you can use :

```
projectionList.add(ProjectionFactoryUtil.groupProperty("myColumn"));
```

I hope you find it helpful.